# Two sets of strings resulted from a set represented by binary and decimal code are in the same class of languages?

Tags: formal-languages

Two sets of strings resulted from a set represented by binary and decimal code are in  the same class of languages as regular languages,context-free languages,context-sentive languages ,computable languages and c.e.language?

For example,a set of number is represented by binary code,every number in the set form a 0-1 string,suppose the set of string is in RL,CFL,CSL,CL,c.e.L if the set of number is represented by decimal code,the set of strings is in the same class of the corresponding binary one?

since the transformation algorithm is in P,they seem to have to be in the same class.

second question:under what condition is the set of strings resulted from the sets of numbers in  RL,CFL,CSL,CL,c.e.L?or the set of strings resulted from what  sets of numbers  is in  RL,CFL,CSL,CL,c.e.L?

Comment: This is hard to parse. Do you mean you have a set of numbers and you consider X the binary string representing these numbers and Y the decimal string and you want to know if they are in the same language classes?

Comment: Can it not be done by a transducer which preserved these classes?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg, every number in a set of numbers corresponds to a string in a language by representing itself with binary code or decimal code.The two languages of the number set by different representation of binary base and decimal base is in the same class?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg,I am not sure,so I post the questions to ask for proof or reference.

Comment: To detail the answer of Benjamin Steinberg: you have a transducer (i.e. an finite-state machine) that can change between binary and decimal representation. All the classes of languages you mentioned are preserved by applying a transducer, so the answer to your question is yes.